# I am getting Hadoop streaming command failed error when I run Map, reduce programms in R console

Tags: r, hadoop-streaming

My map,reduce programs located in directory /usr/local/hadoop/stock/ and I also created stock directory in hdfs and kept my table.csv yahoo file. when I execute below code I am getting Streaming Command Failed. Please help me.

code:

```
system(paste("hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-  streaming-1.0.3.jar",
+ " -input /stock/table.csv",
+ " -output /stock/outputs",
+ " -mapper /usr/local/hadoop/stock/stock_mapper.R",
+ " -reducer /usr/local/hadoop/stock/stock_reducer.R",
+ " -file /usr/local/hadoop/stock/stock_mapper.R",
+ " -file /usr/local/hadoop/stock/stock_reducer.R"))
```

result:

```
packageJobJar: [/usr/local/hadoop/stock/stock_mapper.R, /usr/local    /hadoop/stock/stock_reducer.R, /app/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-unjar3959532939787124658/] [] /tmp/streamjob8499584496084837507.jar tmpDir=null
15/05/03 15:31:20 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
15/05/03 15:31:20 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
15/05/03 15:31:20 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to     process : 1
15/05/03 15:31:22 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/app/hadoop    /tmp/mapred/local]
15/05/03 15:31:22 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job:     job_201505031351_0006
15/05/03 15:31:22 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
15/05/03 15:31:22 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:54311 -kill job_201505031351_0006
15/05/03 15:31:22 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking  URL:http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201505031351_0006
15/05/03 15:31:23 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
15/05/03 15:39:43 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
15/05/03 15:39:43 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
15/05/03 15:39:43 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:54311 -kill job_201505031351_0006
15/05/03 15:39:44 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201505031351_0006
15/05/03 15:39:44 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201505031351_0006_m_000000
15/05/03 15:39:44 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Command Failed!
```